# Counter in while loop does not increase

Tags: java, while-loop, counter

I need to develop a scholarship application in Java. I need to print the successful application in output.

Why a counter in this code does not increase if I for a second person?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Application a = new Application();
    LinkedList lList = new LinkedList();
    boolean bEligible = false;
    int scholarship;
    int scholarshipAmount = 500000;
    int setiStudyLevel;
    int counter;

    while(scholarshipAmount != 0)
    {
      counter = 1;
      System.out.println("");    
      System.out.println("**Welcome to scholarship  applications  offered  by  Smart Foundation**");    
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("Please Enter Your Name");
      a.setsName(input.next());

      System.out.println("1–Pre Diploma, 2–Diploma, 3–Degree");
      System.out.println("Please Enter Your Study Level");
      a.setiStudyLevel(input.nextInt());

      System.out.println("Please Enter Your Personality Score");
      a.setiPersonalityScore(input.nextInt());

      System.out.println("Please Enter Your Parents Income");
      a.setdParentsIncome(input.nextDouble());

      String sName = a.getsName();
      int iStudyLevel = a.getiStudyLevel();
      int iPersonalityScore = a.getiPersonalityScore();
      double dParentsIncome = a.getdParentsIncome();

      if (iStudyLevel == 1)
      {
        scholarship = 15000;
        scholarshipAmount = scholarshipAmount - scholarship;
      }
      else if (iStudyLevel == 2)
      {
        scholarship = 50000;
        scholarshipAmount = scholarshipAmount - scholarship;
      }
      else if (iStudyLevel == 3)
      {
        scholarship = 500000;
        scholarshipAmount = scholarshipAmount - scholarship;
      }

   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("*****Result*****"); 
   System.out.println("Name:"+sName);
   System.out.println("1–Pre Diploma, 2–Diploma, 3–Degree");
   System.out.println("Study Level:"+iStudyLevel);
   System.out.println("Personality Score:"+iPersonalityScore);
   System.out.println("Parents Income:"+dParentsIncome);

    if(iPersonalityScore <=90)
    {
        if(dParentsIncome >=3000)
        {
            System.out.println("YOU ARE NOT ELIGIBLE FOR SCHOLARSHIP ");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("YOU ARE ELIGIBLE FOR SCHOLARSHIP ");
            bEligible = true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("YOU ARE ELIGIBLE FOR SCHOLARSHIP ");
    }

   System.out.println("");

   System.out.println( "RM"+(scholarshipAmount)+" left!!");
   System.out.println("");

   if (scholarshipAmount <= 0)
   {
       System.out.println(" Scholarship Quota is Full!");
   }

   counter++;

   System.out.println(counter);
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you reset your counter to 1 on each loop

Change this:

```
while(scholarshipAmount != 0)
{
counter = 1;
```

to this

```
int counter = 1;//or maybe 0
while(scholarshipAmount != 0)
{
```

Comment: You are welcome. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted on any questions you get correct answers to.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be,

```
while(scholarshipAmount > 0)
    {
      //remaining code
```

Comment: thanks pranit i should consider using this next time